# convert rdd to dataframe without schema in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I'm trying to convert an rdd to dataframe with out any schema.
I tried below code. It's working fine, but the dataframe columns are getting **shuffled**.

```
def f(x):
    d = {}
    for i in range(len(x)):
        d[str(i)] = x[i]
    return d
rdd = sc.textFile("test")
df = rdd.map(lambda x:x.split(",")).map(lambda x :Row(**f(x))).toDF()
df.show()
```

Comment: You could read the data as a dataframe instead of converting the rdd.

Comment: what do you mean by shuffled?

Comment: order of columns is getting shuffled @ramesh

Comment: Yes but rdd i need to convert is processed with other changes.@shaido

Comment: you solution will not work in real data as you are using the values as column names and each rows will have different values. I would agree with @Shaido's comment on using sqlContext as it will use the first line as headder

Comment: Okay, is there any other way to convert rdd to dataframe without schema ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to specify a schema, do not convert use `Row` in the RDD. If you simply have a normal `RDD` (not an `RDD[Row]`) you can use `toDF()` directly.

```
df = rdd.map(lambda x: x.split(",")).toDF()
```

You can give names to the columns using `toDF()` as well,

```
df = rdd.map(lambda x: x.split(",")).toDF("col1_name", ..., "colN_name")
```

---

If what you have is an `RDD[Row]` you need to actually know the type of each column. This can be done by specifying a schema or as follows

```
val df = rdd.map({ 
  case Row(val1: String, ..., valN: Long) => (val1, ..., valN)
}).toDF("col1_name", ..., "colN_name")
```